# Angular Datatable not filtering with column reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-datatables

In JavaScript, I have

```
$scope.dtOptionsCandidate = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withColReorder()
    .withLightColumnFilter({
        1: {"type": "text"},
        2: {"type": "text"},
        3: {"type": "text"}
    });
```

with other options. And in HTML, I have a table with four columns. It works well when I don't move the columns. However, when the columns are moved, the search boxes do not work well. Any solution?

Here is the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uPv8FoUrJkQWnEaE2AQY?p=preview

script.js has the column move logic.

After adding .withLightColumnFilter function, here is my Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6qTGzNWOnGGCYS3f3yi?p=preview

script.js has the .withLightColumnFilter implementation

As you can see in web console, I have error and could not proceed forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need user call `<script>` in correct order.

Comment: @Tristan This actually is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: @TinyGiant I edited this post to make all the words in it visible. It's still very low quality though.

Comment: @MrLister it is low quality for sure, but the VLQ flag should be used for posts with severe content or formatting problems, not short answers. This post still does not qualify for flags or recommending deletion in the LQPRQ. It may warrant Downvotes and delete votes from 20k+ rep users, but it isn't flag worthy.